# How to have Discord bot edit embed message in this case?

Tags: javascript, string, discord, discord.js

Right now, I have a discord bot that will set up a "sign-up" for a game.
[image: sign up embed]

What I'm looking for is for users to be able to message "+join (class)" to sign up for a slot. So if I said "+join Soldier", it would put my name in the slot to look like this:

[image: example]

If all the slots are full or if a staff member types "+close", it will close sign-ups for the current game. I know I'll have to use the .edit function to replace the embed with a new one that's the same but the user's name has been put into the slot, but I'm really not sure how to do that, especially because this involves two separate javascript files. I truly appreciate all help. Thank you so much! :)

NewGameCommand.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = class NewgameCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('newgame', 'managment', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      return message.channel.send("Only staff members can set up games!");
    }
    let gameEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('')
      .setDescription('')
      .setColor("#FF0000")
    const twoCitiesMissionsDisplayed = "\`\`\`\n1 - Empire Escalation\n2 - Metro Malice\n3 - Hamlet Hostility\n4 - Bavarian Botbash\`\`\`";
    const twoCitiesMissionsArray = ['Empire Escalation', 'Metro Malice', 'Hamlet Hostility', 'Bavarian Botbash'];
    const numOfMissions = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
    const cancelWords = ['cancel', 'quit', 'stop', '+cancel', '+quit', '+stop'];
    const mvmChannel = client.channels.cache.get('787130524703129611');
    let classMapDefault = new Map();
    classMapDefault['Soldier'] = '';
    classMapDefault['Demo/Pyro'] = '';
    classMapDefault['Heavy'] = '';
    classMapDefault['Medic'] = '';
    classMapDefault['Engineer'] = '';
    classMapDefault['Scout'] = '';
   
    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
    message.reply("which   Two Cities mission?");
    message.channel.send(twoCitiesMissionsDisplayed);
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
      if(cancelWords.includes(collected.first().content)) {
        return message.channel.send("Canceled.");
      }
      let missionNumString = collected.first().content;
      // if they don't choose 1, 2, 3 or 4
      if(!numOfMissions.includes(missionNumString)) {
        return message.channel.send("Invalid mission number!")
      }  
      let missionNum = parseInt(missionNumString) - 1;
      let missionName = twoCitiesMissionsArray[missionNum];
      message.channel.send(`Great, we'll be playing the ${missionName} mission this week! Are we playing with the default class set? (yes/no)`);
      message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
        if(cancelWords.includes(collected.first().content)) {
          return message.channel.send("Canceled.");
        }
        let classResponseArray = collected.first().content;
        let classResponse = classResponseArray[0].toLowerCase();
        if (classResponse.charAt(0) === 'y') {
          let classMap = classMapDefault;
          const class1 = 'Soldier';
          const class2 = 'Demo/Pyro';
          const class3 = 'Heavy';
          const class4 = 'Medic';
          const class5 = 'Engineer';
          const class6 = 'Scout';
          message.channel.send('Got it! What time? (PST)\nFormat it like \`6:30\` or \`7:00\`');
          message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
            if(cancelWords.includes(collected.first().content)) {
              return message.channel.send("Canceled.");
            }
            let timeResponse = collected.first().content;
            gameEmbed.setTitle(`New MvM Mondays Game! This Monday @ ${timeResponse} PST.`);
            let gameDescription = `Tour: ️Two Cities\nMission: ${missionName}\n`
            let class1description = `${class1}: open⭕\n`
            let class2description = `${class2}: open⭕\n`
            let class3description = `${class3}: open⭕\n`
            let class4description = `${class4}: open⭕\n`
            let class5description = `${class5}: open⭕\n`
            let class6description = `${class6}: open⭕\n`
            gameDescription = gameDescription + '\`\`\`' + class1description + class2description + class3description + class4description + class5description + class6description + "\`\`\`";
            gameEmbed.setDescription(gameDescription);
            let openOrClosed = `OPEN`;
            gameEmbed.setFooter(`Sign-ups: ${openOrClosed}`);
            message.channel.send(`${timeResponse} it is! Here's what will be sent to ${mvmChannel}:`);
            message.channel.send(gameEmbed);
            message.channel.send('Ready to send? Type \"yes\" to send or \"no\" to cancel.');
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
              if(cancelWords.includes(collected.first().content)) {
                return message.channel.send("Canceled.");
              }
              let sendResponseArray = collected.first().content;
              let sendResponse = sendResponseArray[0].toLowerCase();
              if (sendResponse.charAt(0) === 'y') {
                mvmChannel.send(gameEmbed);
                message.send(`MvM Mondays Sign-up created in ${mvmChannel}!`);
              } else if (sendResponse.charAt(0) === 'n') {
                message.channel.send("Canceled.");
              } else {
                return message.reply('you just had to say \"yes\" or \"no\"!');
              }      
            }).catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
            })
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })
        } else if (classResponse.charAt(0) === 'n') {
          return message.channel.send('I only know the default class sets right now...');
        } else {
          return message.reply('you just had to say \"yes\" or \"no\"!');
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })  
  }
}
```

JoinCommand.js:

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class JoinCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('join', 'member', []);
  }

  run(client, message, args) {
    const mvmClass = args[0];
    message.channel.send(message.author.toString() + ` joined as ${mvmClass}!`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `<Message>.edit()` on the https://discord.js.org page.

Example:

```
let text = "Hello world!";
message.channel.send(text).then(msg=> {
    text = text.replace("world", "my friend") // "Hello my friend!"
    msg.edit(text)
}
```

or

```
let msg = message.channel.send("Hello world");
msg.edit("Hello my friend");
```

Please read the documentation again! Or just google it first.

Comment: Right. I guess I was more wondering how I can create a message in one js file and reference it in a different js file.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. You mean like create an Embed in one js file and then send it in another js file ?

Comment: Basically, yeah. Create and send it in one js file and edit it in another js file. I'm thinking I might be able to store the messageID in a json and edit the message by referencing the messageID.

Comment: Yeah, you can fetch the Message and then edit it, `client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID").channels.get("CHANNEL_ID").messages.fetch("MESSAGE_ID").then((m) => {})` after that you just simply use `m.edit("YOUR_TEXT")`